# How to test against a variable in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

How do you do a test against a value that is a variable? I know you can test against a fixed value, e.g.

```
<c:if test="${thing.subthing > 12}">
  Subthing's big
</c:if>
<c:if test="${thing.subthing <= 12}">
  Subthing's small
</c:if>
```

How would I do that using a variable? Something like:

```
<c:set value="12" var="sizeDelimiter"></c:set>
<c:if test="${thing.subthing} > ${sizeDelimiter}">
  Subthing's big
</c:if>
<c:if test="${thing.subthing} <= ${sizeDelimiter}">
  Subthing's small
</c:if>
```

Comment: <c:if test="${thing.subthing > sizeDelimiter}">

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate expression twice in the `c:if` tag's `test` attribute, so you have to use only one expression.

```jsp
<c:set value="12" var="sizeDelimiter"/>
<c:if test="${thing.subthing > sizeDelimiter}">
  Subthing's big
</c:if>
<c:if test="${thing.subthing <= sizeDelimiter}">
  Subthing's small
</c:if>
```